# How to open System Settings>Appearance with command line

Tags: 16.04, appearance

How to open System Settings>Appearance with terminal? i.e., what is the right command for that?

I try `gnome-control-center appearance`, but it does not work as it is not one of the panels in gnome-control-center as follows:

[image]

Comment: Exactly which settings do you want to change using the terminal?

Comment: @Nmath OP doesn't want to make any changes using the terminal; they want to open the program from the terminal, starting at this particular panel.

Answer (score 1):

What works on my 20.04 system is not `gnome-control-center appearance` as you would expect, but:

```
gnome-control-center ubuntu
```

I found this out by starting up `gnome-control-center` and navigating to the Appearances tab; then starting up `dconf-editor` and navigating to the `org.gnome.ControlCenter` tab, where the value of the key `last-panel` was `ubuntu`.

Hope this works on your 16.04 system too. There is no Ubuntu panel in the panel list, nor in the man page, probably because this is a Ubuntu-specific modification to the Gnome framework.